# How to use formattings of the caption-package within the hvfloat-package?

Tags: captions

With the caption-package I'm declaring the style of my table- and figure-captions:

```
\RequirePackage[singlelinecheck=false,
                listof=true,
                tableposition=top]{caption}%
\DeclareCaptionFont{dgcapfont}{\small\sffamily\raggedright}
\DeclareCaptionFont{dgclbfont}{\bfseries}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=colon,
                     labelfont=dgclbfont,
                     font=dgcapfont,
                     position=top,
                     skip=8\p@}%
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=colon,
                      labelfont=dgclbfont,
                      font=dgcapfont,
                      skip=4mm}%
```

But these declarements do not affect the captions within a hvfloat table or figure. Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1):

please be more specific because this works for me (your definition and an example from the doc):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false,
                listof=true,
                tableposition=top]{caption}%
\DeclareCaptionFont{dgcapfont}{\small\sffamily\raggedright}
\DeclareCaptionFont{dgclbfont}{\bfseries}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=colon,
                      labelfont=dgclbfont,
                      font=dgcapfont,
                      skip=4mm}%
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\begin{document}

\hvFloat[%
     floatPos=htb,%
     capWidth=0.5,% of \columnwidth
     capPos=r,%
     capVPos=c,%
     objectPos=c]{figure}{\includegraphics{rose}}% or any other image
     [Caption beside object and vertically centered]{%
     Caption vertically centered right beside the float with a caption
         width of \texttt{0.5\textbackslash columnwidth} and \texttt{
         floatcapsep=5pt} (the default)}{fig:1}    
\end{document}
```